# Unable to Upload picture that has been taken by camera. using apache cordova and visual studio

Tags: cordova, cross-platform, visual-studio-cordova

Hello i am using Visual Studio 2017.

and code has been written in Apache cordova.
i am using two of the standard plugin of cordova that has been added through visual studio 2017 config.xml editor.

i am following same code as documentation suggest.
but getting following error in Visual Studio 2017 simulator.

why i need to use this callback editor. weather api url of file upload is already online?
[image]

here is my code that getting executed without any exception.

```
   var win = function (r) {
            navigator.camera.cleanup();
            retries = 0;
            alert('Done!');
        }

        var fail = function (error) {
            if (retries == 0) {
                retries++
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#btnUploadPicture").trigger("click");
                }, 1000)
            } else {
                retries = 0;
                navigator.camera.cleanup();
                alert('Ups. Something wrong happens!');
            }
        }

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = $("#txtIMEI").html();
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        options.params = {}; // if we need to send parameters to the server request
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://localhost:3199/api/Vehicles"), win, fail, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **Ripple** emulator? I would stay as far away as possible from it. Try in a real device or a real Android emulator and report if the error persists... you can debug from VS as it runs on a device or emulator.

Comment: hello @andreszs i was using Visual Studio Android Emulator. problem still persists in emulator. i did use web browser simulation. for developer purpose and than install it on actual device so job get done. but this problem is till persists. thanks anyways.